# Design a table with exact width for Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, stylesheet, css

My table is working well if I define the max width in with CSS, but chrome ignore them and doesn't show as expected.

the same problem notice before [Chrome, Safari ignoring max-width in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019604/chrome-safari-ignoring-max-width-in-table)

Is there any way to define the max-width for table inside chrome.

Comment: Can you give a snippet of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer in the other question you linked pointed out, tables are neither block nor inline and max-width only applies to block or replaced elements. So it seems Chrome is working as the html spec says--as unhelpful as that is.

Not sure if it'll help, but `max-width` does work for `td`'s. Perhaps you can come up with an alternative design that uses that fact.