# joomla 3.0 responsive css table width

Tags: css, joomla

I use joomla 3.0 for all of my websites and am struggling with table widths in responsive templates beez3 and protostar. I can't understand why the tables aren't automatically responsive to start with since the templates are "responsive".

I've researched css fixes including creating special @media css files that totally reshape the way the table is presented but for the moment all I want to do is simply display the table in a non responsive format that is just width:100% of the device that it's being displayed on. I have tried creating a special div around the table but it didn't work for me. I'm not an expert in css so if someone could just spell it out for me that would be very helpful.

The table i'm currently struggling with is found here:
http://www.skiptech.com.au/index.php/skip-bin-hire-types-sizes

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out with an explanation of why tables aren't the best at being responsive: [Chrome, Safari ignoring max-width in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019604/chrome-safari-ignoring-max-width-in-table)

Basically, tables aren't a block level element, so they don't respond well to having a width that limits them. Most browsers allow you to stretch them to a greater width nicely, but not shrink them easily.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, after more investigation it seems that it's the font size that is preventing the css changes from working. The font simply won't shrink down past a certain point so i'm guessing i might need to somehow change the fontsize for table text only? It only is an issue for me in portrait mode on the iphone....any tips anyone?