# background-size cover in a table

Tags: html, css, css-tables, background-size

Trying to use background size cover in a table and not getting the results I am after.

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/pp9st63L/1/

```
.image th {
    background-size: cover !important;
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
}
```

The data columns (not including left most column) should be equal width, but the number of columns is variable. Sometimes 3 and other times 4 (including left headline column).

The width of these data columns should be equal and sufficient that the background image can cover. If there is any long data in the other.  Currently the width of the columns is purely related to the data in those columns. I would like to override this behavior with CSS and set max widths for columns and make them equal width. So the background-size cover will work.

Any thoughts on how to get this to work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019604/chrome-safari-ignoring-max-width-in-table?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete `display:block` and `max-width`, use `width` for  `table cell`. `background-size:cover` works for me. For some 'beautiful' you may also use `background-position:50% 50%` or `background-position:50% 0px` for `images`. For `table-cells` same `width` properties (`30% 30% 30%`  or `30px 30px 30px 30px`) is a point to set those `width` always be the same.

P.S. Sorry for my very bad English.

**UPD**

Also set `width` for the first `col`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pp9st63L/4/)

**UPD 2**

Please check, that `tr { td {...} }` was error. You should use `tr td {...}` .
Also check, that for set image properties you should use `background-image` property in `tags`.
And `width:auto` I wrote specially to show that you don't need set `width` for narrow column to set it width to all other space of table.
Also `width` for `table-cell` is a `min-width`. So, text in `cells` can change the `width`. But `it` could be change by hyphenation (`word-wrap`).

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/pp9st63L/8/)

Comment: Thanks @cnapoB - if you remove that 4th column the heading column (left one) no longer is narrow  (>  width:60px;) see: http://jsfiddle.net/pp9st63L/5/

Comment: @Martin please see the UPD2