# Max-width in Pseudo class?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have a css tooltip attached to a span as follows:

```
<span class="mytooltip" data-mytooltip="Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. ">
    Has Tooltip
</span>
```

The CSS is in short:

```
.mytooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; 
}
.mytooltip:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-mytooltip);
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.7rem;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  padding: .3rem 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 400px; 
}
```

In `.mytooltip:hover:after{}`
`width: 400px` and 
`max-width: 400px; white-space: nowrap;`
works as expected. The later doesn't make much sense, because though the pseudo element has the right width, the text is floating over, when it's longer than 400px.
Is there a way to use max-width on the pseudo element with the text wrapped inside?

I'd be very grateful for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I can only suggest tooltip text wrapped manually

```css
.mytooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; 
  margin:15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:visible;
}

.mytooltip:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-mytooltip);
  display: table-cell;
  margin-top: 0.7rem;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  padding: .3rem 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  max-width: 400px; 
  white-space:pre;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<span class="mytooltip" data-mytooltip="Text here. Text here. &#xa;Text here. Text here. Text here. &#xa;Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. ">
    Has Tooltip
</span>
```

Comment: In Chrome the text is cut with ... at the end, when longer than the max-width and I can't display it. That was not the target. Do you maybe have a solution where the whole text is visible?

Comment: it works because you have set position: relative, but that makes the tooltip stretch the field in which it's in, what it shouldn't. I tried width: auto on the element, what sounded like a good idea, but still, sorry, max-width is not recognised in the pseudo element with your data and position:absolute.

Comment: Finally, I can only suggest tooltip text wrapped manually, see snippet again

Comment: Sounded like a good idea. But html tags in content of a pseudo element are not allowed, not even escaped. It's maybe just not possible with max-width and wrap in a pseudo element. Still, thank you.

Comment: Yes it works as a line break. But that is not what i wanted to achieve. I wanted to have wrapped text in a container with a max-width in a pseudo element as a tooltip, what is a quite common use. Question is if  a pure CSS solution is possible with some minimum layout options. I'd say now it isn't.

Comment: This question might shed some light on the reason for your problems. The display element must be a block element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019604/chrome-safari-ignoring-max-width-in-table